# Libreoffice won't launch ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice

so I try to use libreoffice only to discover that it never started, it show the start screen for half a second and that's about it.

trying to launch it in console yield the following result

```
spark:~$ libreoffice
free(): invalid pointer
Application Error
```

I have no idea what is causing that pointer error since I did not install any addon. 
I'm currently trying to delete the .config for libreoffice to see of the profile is an issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

deleting the `~/.config/libreoffice`  did the trick

Comment: Click on the checkmark at left to show this answer solves your problem, and other folks can reference it more easily.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem.
Writer would launch, but Calc only showed the title bar.
This only worked temporarily:

```
cd .config/libreoffice

rm -r *
```

This was the fix:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

I support something was amiss with the application.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers from [@gothsparkimvu](https://askubuntu.com/users/258693/gothsparkimvu) and [@carl-moser](https://askubuntu.com/users/745602/carl-moser), I also had an icon for LibreOffice Impress in my favorites toolbar on the left. So I had to delete it, `sudo apt install libreoffice` and then recreate a generic Libre Office favorite.